# triangularizable matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, matrix-equations

Given invertible matrices $X,Y$, is there a way to find $A = A(X,Y)$ so that $AXA^T = Y$?

I am interest in the case where all the matrices are over some $\textit{finite}$ field, say $GF(2)$ for simplicity, and $Y$ is triangular (that is why the title).

I am primarily interested on finding $A$ and not its existence.

Comment: I imagine that you're interested in finding *efficiently* $A$. As you work in finite fields, there is a finite number of matrices and you can therefore test easily all of them. Right?

Comment: I disagree with the usage of ''easily'', but anyway, as mentioned I am interested on constructing $A(X,Y)$ given $X,Y$. An algorithm that gives $A$ is fine, but obviously not exhaustive search.

Comment: By *easily*, I mean easy to program. Execution time is another story...

Comment: Reduce $X$ to a canonical form $PXP^T=J$; do the same for $Y$, $QYQ^T=J$, then $A=Q^{-1}P$. If they don't reduce to the same form, then there is no such $A$, since similarity is an equivalence relation.

Comment: Aren't the reductions to canonical form done by conjugation? Could you please elaborate how to "reduce $X$ to a canonical form $PXP^T = J$? Please keep in mind that I am interested over $GF(2)$, so characteristic 2. Thanks!

Comment: The LAMA paper [*"Triangularizing matrices over $GF(2)$ by congruence"*](https://doi.org/10.1080/03081089708818495) by Botha (1997) has characterised which matrices are congruent to a triangular matrix over $GF(2)$. It may be helpful.